# How to use Image1.Bitmap.BitmapChanged;

Tags: firemonkey, tbitmap

Bitmap.BitmapChanged; is protected in FMX.Graphics so I cannot use the procedure.

Useing a TImage or TImageControler I am drawing a line but the line does not show.

I am using this snippet:

```
imgc1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
imgc1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(FStartPoint,FEndPoint, 100);
imgc1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
imgc1.Bitmap.BitmapChanged;  // the original example said that this would redraw the image. In my CE Rio IDE the BitmapChanged is undefind. How can I use it?
```

Draw the line. IDE cannot find BitmapChanged.

Answer (score 0):

BitmapChanged is a protected member. I need to write some code to handle the OnBitmapChanged event. 
I understand now. Almost 30 years of developing in Delphi and this is the first time I have run into protected members. The examples I was using must not have been compiled else the writer would have had the same error that I had.

Answer (score 0):

`TBitmap.BitmapChanged()` is a `virtual` method that simply fires the public `TBitmap.OnChange` event. Since it is `protected`, you can use an accessor class to reach it:

```pascal
type
  TBitmapAccess = class(TBitmap)
  end;

TBitmapAccess(imgc1.Bitmap).BitmapChanged;
```

However, this is not really needed. `TImage` assigns its own internal `OnChange` event handler to its `Bitmap`.  So it should react to changes to the `Bitmap` automatically.  But, if for some reason it does not, the correct way to refresh the `TImage` is to call its `Repaint()` method:

```pascal
imgc1.Repaint;
```

Which is exactly what `TImage`'s internal `OnChange` handler does:

```pascal
constructor TImage.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FBitmap := TBitmap.Create(0, 0);
  FBitmap.OnChange := DoBitmapChanged;
  ...
end;

procedure TImage.DoBitmapChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Repaint;
  UpdateEffects;
end;
```